# jQuery UI Spinner with letters A-Z or other custom range

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

Is there a way to customize jQuery UI spinner, so that A-Z letters (or any custom range) is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Here's a simple example using A-Z, adapted from the [provided time example](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time):

```
$.widget("ui.alphaspinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
        min: 65,
        max: 90
    },
    _parse: function(value) {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
            return value.charCodeAt(0);
        }
        return value;
    },
    _format: function(value) {
        return String.fromCharCode(value);
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
$("#my-input").alphaspinner();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4nwTc/1/

The above example creates a new widget called `alphaspinner` that inherits from `spinner`. You can do this for just one spinner with the following:

```
$(function() {
    var spinner = $("#alpha-spinner").spinner({
        min: 65,
        max: 90
    }).data("spinner");

    spinner._parse = function (value) {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
            return value.charCodeAt(0);
        }
        return value;        
    };

    spinner._format = function (value) {
        return String.fromCharCode(value);        
    }
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4nwTc/2/

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. That: $.widget("ui.alphaspinner", ... looks interesting? What is it?

Comment: That's just creating a new widget called `alphaspinner`. You could also do this by overriding the `_format` and `_parse` function on an individual widget instance (I'll update my answer with an example)

Answer (score 0):

I built up on Andrews code and built a spinner widget that takes a string array for input.

You can see the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245047/jquery-spinner-with-strings-as-input/18845945#18845945).