# How to create an arcade style name input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an arcade style name input for a highscore list. I'd like it to work using just the arrow keys on the keyboard, so up/down arrow for character selection and left/right for input box selection. I'm using a MakeyMakey for this project, so I want to keep user/keyboard interaction as minimal as possible.

Right now I'm rendering `select` boxes containing the entire alphabet in `option` tags, however, a `select` box always drops down, and your choice has to be confirmed using `Enter` or a mouse-click.

I'd like to stay at least a little semantically correct on the input, so I'm thinking 3 inputs that each select one letter, then concatenating these in a hidden input field, of which I can pass the value to Rails.

I'm using the following jQuery-plugin (from: http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/navigate-form-fields-with-arrow-keys.html) to navigate between `select` boxes using the left/right arrow keys.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.formNavigation = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      $(this).find('select').on('keyup', function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
          case 39:
            $(this).closest('td').next().find('select').focus();
            break;
          case 37:
            $(this).closest('td').prev().find('select').focus();
        }
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

What I want to implement next is three input boxes that have the entire (infinitely looped) alphabet as choices, navigable by up/down arrow. I'd rather not type out the entire alphabet so I want to generate the options for each box and probably bind a keyhandler somewhere. How would I generate such an input box and integrate the required code into my existing script?

#### Screenshots

This is how it looks now:

[image: Current situation]

Ideally, it will look like this:

[image: Ideal situation]

Comment: Screen shots of before and after?

Comment: There is no after yet, I'm asking for help regarding that.

Comment: you may get some more bites if you put what you have so far into a jsfiddle

Comment: Searched for letter spinner jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496943/jquery-ui-spinner-with-letters-a-z-or-other-custom-range

Comment: The jsfiddle provided in the answer you linked doesn't function (in Chrome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Banana had a great answer, but I wanted to try making it look a little more expressive.

```js
KEYCODES = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

$('.cyclic_input').on('keydown',function(ev){
    input = $(this);
    val = $(this).text();
    
    switch (ev.keyCode) {   
      case KEYCODES.right:
        input.next().focus();
        break;
      case KEYCODES.left:
        input.prev().focus();
        break;
      case KEYCODES.up:
        input.text(advanceCharBy(val, 1));
        break;
      case KEYCODES.down:
        input.text(advanceCharBy(val, -1));
        break;
      default:
        if (ev.keyCode >= 65 && ev.keyCode <= 65 + 26) {
            input.text(String.fromCharCode(ev.keyCode));
            input.next().focus();
        }
    };
    ev.preventDefault();
});

advanceCharBy = function(char, distance) {
    oldCode = char.charCodeAt(0);
    newCode = 65 + (oldCode - 65 + 26 + distance) % 26;
    return String.fromCharCode(newCode);
};
```

```css
.cyclic_input {
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.cyclic_input:before,
.cyclic_input:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cyclic_input:before {
    content: '▲';
    top: 0;
}

.cyclic_input:after {
    content: '▼';
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cyclic_input" tabindex="0">A</div>
<div class="cyclic_input" tabindex="0">A</div>
<div class="cyclic_input" tabindex="0">A</div>
```

Forked <kbd>**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/oXGQOW)**</kbd> but also works fine in the snippet. My thoughts:

- I don't know keycodes, I don't *want* to know keycodes.
- We're not interested in keypresses on the whole document, just the initials inputs.
- If you must have branching logic, be clear how many paths there are, one.
- If these are our form inputs, then they deserve at least tabindex. In reality I would use `<input>`s but that would have just added a bunch of CSS to the demo.
- The whole point is keyboard support. I'm pretty sure we need to handle the case where a user types a letter.
- Let's not jerk the page around when someone presses an arrow key.

Comment: nice fix, +1. also in the keyboard char input you should advance to the next input.

Comment: Good call! (additional words to appease the vengeful SO gods)

Comment: Good call on the preventDefaults! This solution works even better. Thanks!

Comment: I did really like the possibility to style the active input with a `.active` class in @Banana 's script so I'm adding that in.

Comment: If you want to get technical, the `preventDefault` should *only* occur on arrows or letters, but I thought it would muddy the water a bit in a demo.

The active class is fine for a component like this, although I would rather do my styling with "focus" if the elements are stand-ins for form inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Its rather simple, all you need is a few calculations:

if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("keydown", function(ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode == 39) {
      var idx = $('.active').index();
      var next_idx = (+idx + 1) % $('.cyclic_input').length;
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.cyclic_input').eq(next_idx).addClass('active');
    }
    if (ev.keyCode == 37) {
      var idx = $('.active').index();
      var next_idx = ((+idx - 1) + $('.cyclic_input').length) % $('.cyclic_input').length;
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.cyclic_input').eq(next_idx).addClass('active');
    }

    if (ev.keyCode == 38) {
      var char = $(".active").text();
      var ascii = char.charCodeAt(0);
      var nextAscii = 65 + (ascii + 1 - 65) % 26;
      $(".active").text(String.fromCharCode(nextAscii));
    }
    if (ev.keyCode == 40) {
      var char = $(".active").text();
      var ascii = char.charCodeAt(0);
      var nextAscii = 65 + ((ascii - 1 - 65) + 26) % 26;
      $(".active").text(String.fromCharCode(nextAscii));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cyclic_input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid red;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.active {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cyclic_input active">A</div>
<div class="cyclic_input">A</div>
<div class="cyclic_input">A</div>
```

and here is a <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/zbmzyqtv/)**</kbd>

**PS: the snippet here doesnt work too well, but if you test the code or check the jsfiddle it will work fine.**

Comment: After playing around with this I ended up using this code, because it actually cycles through the elements as well which feels more intuitive and user-friendly. @Sinetheta's script only selects the next one.

Comment: @mplungjan it does, you just need to click on the result window first  :)