# jQuery UI Spinner displaying in hours and minutes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to build a spinner that allows you to increment/decrement by 15 minutes (text input disabled) in the format of:

> 2 hours 15 minutes

Increment

> 2 hours 30 minutes

The [related question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245047/jquery-spinner-with-strings-as-input) top answer seems to be depreciated (.change doesn't trigger anything). The other answers are focused on the question's particular use case and is hard to adapt for my issue.

I would appreciate any help possible

Comment: What I ended up doing was hiding the jQuery UI's input element, adding in a new input element (with same classes for styling) and binding the two together using the { spin: function() {}}  event bind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for your requirement.This is so simple that you just place step:15 so that it will increment your min spinner to 15 min.....Happy coding

```
 <input id="spinner" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#spinner').spinner({
            min: 2,
            max: 20,
            step: 15
        });
    });
</script>
```